# Laptop wifi connectivity dependent on other devices being connected (RaspPi Access Point)

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've been trying to setup a Raspberry Pi as a WiFi router using `hostapd`, yet have encountered a strange issue when trying to connect:

1. Laptop (Macbook Pro 2009) finds WiFi network, yet fails to connect: being too far from  the router named as possible issue.
2. I connect my mobile phone to the WiFi network, after standing a bit closer, and it works fine.
3. Once the phone is connected, my laptop immediately connects to the network (not having been moved), signalling full signal strength.

Could someone explain to me why this is happening on a technological level? Are there maybe ways the Raspberry Pi can be configured, so that all devices are able to connect without this strange workaround?

Comment: Are you using one of those WiFi dongles that switch to a low-power mode after a few seconds of inactivity? That might explain why the range increases when your phone is connected.

Comment: By the way, there's also http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com for RPi-specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It seems this [comment](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4518) may solve my issue, but I'll have to do some testing before I'm entirely sure.